# Using MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.WindowsAzuerActiveDirectory with Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, android, azure, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

Iam creating an applicaiton using Windows azure active directory. Iam following this tutorial http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/partner-xamarin-mobile-services-android-get-started-users/

But when I reach this code :-

```
 private async Task Authenticate()
{
    try
    {
        user = await client.LoginAsync(this, MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.MicrosoftAccount);
        CreateAndShowDialog(string.Format("you are now logged in - {0}", user.UserId), "Logged in!");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        CreateAndShowDialog(ex, "Authentication failed");
    }
}
```

I want to use WindowsAzureActiveDirectory instead of MicrosoftAccount. But I can only see four options ie. Google, facebook, twitter and Microsoft account. How can I use the identity provider as WindowsAzureActiveDirectory?

Any help will be useful as I am just beginning with Xamarin and Azure.